# Horizontal line z-axis not printing correctly

Tags: troubleshooting, support-structures, flashforge-creator, flashprint

I have just started with the FlashForge Creator Pro using the FlashPrint slicer software. I have gotten some nice prints but I am having an issue with a certain print from [this model of a knife](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2895799).

See image below:

[image]

Everything prints fine up to where the blade starts. As you can see, there is horizontal portion of the blade that juts out and, as I predicted, when it tries to print this, there is nothing for it to adhere to so it hangs there and when the extruder moves, it just pulls the filament around with it and creates a mess.

The object file from Thingiverse is designed that way (with it standing upright) and there are pictures on the Thingiverse page of a successfully printed knife. As I am new to this, I am wracking my brain trying to figure out how to print this.

I tried to cut the design and print the handle and blade separately (laying the blade down flat on the print surface) but the blade isn't perfectly flat on the sides so it doesn't lay flat. I suppose I could also just cut the blade and lay it vertically on the print surface but it seems as though it was designed to print in full in one piece.

Any help or any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: While not your question, I'd consider laying the knife down with the spine of the knife on the bed. You'd do this with using support as well. The reason I'm suggesting this is for strength in the blade. Layering the knife up through the blade like you are is going to leave it very weak. Laying it out lengthwise will allow the filament to be laid long as well, which will give it a lot more strength. Just a thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll notice in the screen capture that there is an icon marked "supports." This is precisely the solution required. When selected, the software should construct a series of vertical pillars in the locations required to properly print the horizontal portion of the knife blade.

It's common for Thingiverse models to have a notation Supports (yes/no) to indicate that this feature should be activated. Depending on the capability of your printer, some angles may require supports that are not required on someone else's printer model. There may also be an adjustment for angle reference to cease supports or to require. My printer will handle up to a 50° from vertical without support. Beyond that, more filament is used, but the result is superior to printing without it, as you've discovered.

Note also that support is typically categorized as "from the bed only" or "everywhere." The former prevents support from being generated between vertically separated parts of the model, while the latter permits it. Some models may have, for example, a foot on the bed not requiring support, but the arm directly above the foot does. "From the bed only" means the arm would droop/fail as no support would be generated above that portion of the model.

If you are using the [ReplicatorG 0400 software](http://www.flashforge.com.hk/downloads.html), referenced from the manufacturer's web site, page 11 of the [manual](http://www.flashforge.com.hk/uploads/5/8/1/9/58196085/flashforge_creator_pro_user_manual_en_version04.29.2015.3.2._latest.pdf) will have additional information regarding support within the program.

Comment: Oh perfect, thank you! That screenshot is actually from FlashPrint (from my computer) which is the software the FlashForge Creator Pro recommends. When I went into the 'Supports' screen I was able to see how to set up supports in order to do that. Thank you, I will play around with this to get it right but it looks like that's the answer!